# How to parse an object arrayList to string array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an **arrayList** which contains objects.
I need to parse it to an **array** with all the elements as strings.

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't. Believe it or not, all Strings may be Objects, but not all Objects are Strings. if you're sure they're all Strings, run a stream, map them to strings and collect them into a new List

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should override the toString() method of the class you want to convert to String, in order to produce a descriptive string. (You can use @Data or @ToString lombok annotation)

Second, you can use this to pass from list to array

```
String[] array = objectList.stream().map(element -> element.toString()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: additional note for @Charlie: streams in java are not always faster or nice to read for everyone. You should not pick 1-line solutions if you can't explain them. In that case, think about using the classy simple for-loop. Create an empty array by the ArrayLists size and fill it per loop.

Comment: @LenglBoy streams and lambda's were added in Java 8. We're in Java 16.
They aren't some side feature, they were major changes, well documented and easy to use. If you consider a for loop to be easier to read compared to the line JArgente suggested, maybe the issue is you haven't read up while you should have. I see no problem with the readability or with comprehending that line

Comment: @Stultuske of cause they are easy to read but sometimes not always explaining what they are exactly doing. You can just guess in step 1. And no matter which java version is used: for-loops are often faster and always supported.
You didn't get the point of my suggestion.

Comment: @LenglBoy you didn't mention version in your comment, so indeed, I didn't get that out of it. But, honestly, if you're still on a pre-Java 8 version, it's time to update anyway. Are you actually telling me you don't know what element -> element.toString() does, that you need to guess at what it does?
Something tells me that if you are worried about the 'efficiency' in this bit, you should upgrade your hardware as well

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your object in the list has method `toString` properly overridden, it is better to use method [`Objects::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object)) which allows null-safe conversion of objects to string.

1. Use `for-each` loop:

```java
public static String[] convert(List<MyObject> list) {
    String[] result = new String[list.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (MyObject obj : list) {
        result[i++] = Objects.toString(obj);
    }

    return result;
}
```

2. Use Stream API

```java
public static String[] convert(List<MyObject> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .map(Objects::toString)
               .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```